# how to figure out size in paging in operating system

Tags: memory, memory-management, operating-system, paging, virtual-memory

I don't know how to figure out the size,physical address. And what's the relationship between pages and pages in frame. There are pages of lines in frames right? Thanks!
[image]

Comment: Is this your homework?

Comment: It looks suspiciously like a homework.

Comment: And the size of the `main memory` is missing.

Comment: Does it matter it's home work or not. I'm not asking for a direct answer. I want to know how to do them

Comment: Then you should at least show some effort and what you don't understand. 
Frame are chunks of size `frame size` which are in main memory. While pages, refers to virtual memory, pages that are not yet in `main memory`.

How do you figure out the size of physical address ?
You will be given a logical address, since 512 bytes is 2^9B you need 9 bits for offset. First 9 bits will never change.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40292822/translate-virtual-address-to-physical-address/40293053#40293053

Comment: I figured out page number and offset in the question A and B . But I dont know how to get size using a logical address.

Comment: Don't vandalize your posts.

Answer (score 1):

To get you started, the size of logical page is the same as the size of a physical page frame.

The questions themselves make no sense. "What is the logcail page number?" of what?
"What is the logical page offset" of what?

Comment: i got the offset and page number but don't know the relationship to count the size. even with what you said. the number and offset of the question i guess

Comment: Size of 'main memory' not provided as well.