# Calculating the memory address sizes for paging and offset and page table size.

Tags: memory-management, operating-system, size, paging, page-tables

This question is mostly just to clarify my understanding.

Say I have a 32-bit Computer, with virtual memory space of **2^32 bytes.**

Memory paging is used, each page is **2^8 bytes.**

So the memory address sizes are **24 bits**. Since **(2^32/2^8 = 2^24 bytes)**.

And the offset would be **8 bits**? This I do not quite understand. Since I know that the total address is *32*, and 24 is already taken by the pages, so the remainder is the offset of *8*.

Lastly for the page size. If each physical memory address is stored in **32 bits** (**4 bytes**), the table size would be **2^26 (2^24 * 2^2)**. Is this correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [translate virtual address to physical address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40292822/translate-virtual-address-to-physical-address)

Comment: @TonyTannous that helps a bit, but I wanted clarification on whether I understood how the values are calculated and if I was correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Page Table size = number of entries`*`size of entry

In your case, each page is `2^8 bytes`, that is - you need 8 bits offset. You got that one right.

This leaves us with 24 bits for `Page`. 2^24 different pages.

Size of **page-table** for process `X` is: 2^24*Entry-Size. which is not provided by you here.

Lets assume it needs 32 bits per entry. Then, 2^24*32 = 2^24*2^5 = 2^29 bits.