# Calculating a Real Address from a Virtual Address

Tags: memory-address, cpu-registers, addressing-mode

Below is an example of a question from a work sheet of my Computer Engineering course. Up until now we've been given some information to work with, such as the address space of the device, the RAM memory capacity, and so on, so I might be overcomplicating things.

I don't get what the colons are for or how to proceed with only this information, anyone mind explaining me?

---

Calculate the Real Address of the following Virtual Addresses:

```
a) 1000H:1F00H

b) 1001H:0011H

c) 1209H:0011H
```

Comment: Doesn't quite answer your question, but relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40292822/translate-virtual-address-to-physical-address

Comment: @code11 I've seen that post too, thanks either way. I haven't found anything yet that used the colons without giving any other info.