# Converting virtual to physical address

Tags: operating-system

I apologize this is for an assignment but I'm having trouble finding info online on how to do this. And my professor fails to answer my emails. I do have some work done on it but I'm not sure if it's right.

1. Assume you have a virtual memory system with 32-bit virtual and physical addresses. Assume also that your page size is 4KB.

(a) How many bits are needed for the offset part of the virtual address?

12 bits

(b) How many bits are needed for the page number part of the virtual address?

16 bits

(c) How many different page numbers does this system support? (You can express this as a power of two)

2 ^ 4

(d) If a page table entry takes up 4 bytes, how much space in MB would a page table for this system take up if it were stored in physical memory?

4MB

Mostly I need help on how to approach this. I would appreciate any help :) Thank you everyone for your time.

2) Given the assumptions above and the page map below, translate the following virtual addresses to physical addresses:

```
Page Number     Frame Number
0               4
1               0
2               3
3               5
4               1
5               2
```

(a) 0

(b) 42

(c) 4096

(d) 5000

(e) 10000

(f) 20000

Physical addresses: These are the answers I have. I don't know if they're right. They're supposed to be expressed in base 10.

A. 16384

B. 16426

C. 0

D. 904

E. 14096

F. 7712

Comment: Possible duplicate of [translate virtual address to physical address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40292822/translate-virtual-address-to-physical-address)

Comment: Yes, this is the question I had looked at while searching online. I'm still having trouble understanding it though.

Comment: I can say that your answers to 1.b and 1.c aren't right (hints: if a virtual address is 32 bits and gets split into 2 fields, page number and offset, then the sizes of both of the fields has to add up to 32 bits. If an integer has N bits, then there are 2^N possible values it can hold).

Comment: Okay I think I get what you're saying. So 1.b should be 20 bits and 1.c should be 2^5 power?